# Jenkins multibranch pipeline postbuild only on specific branch (declarative)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

How can you create a pipeline that does its stages on every branch, but the postbuild action only on specific branches.

I have seen the `when {branch 'production'}` option, but it seems to me, that this only works for stage blocks and not for post blocks.
Is there a way to do something like

```
pipeline {
  agent { any }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        bat script:"echo build" 
      }
      post {
        always {
          when {
            branch 'production'
          }
          bat script:"echo publish"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the `if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'production')` seems to be only for scripted pipelines

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to the Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Conditional post section in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350384/conditional-post-section-in-jenkins-pipeline) has an answer: use `script` and `if` inside the post condition.

```
    post {
        always {
            script {
                if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'production') {
                    // I have not verified whether your step works here;
                    // conditional emailext works as expected.
                    bat script:"echo publish"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```